# Angular 2 local development environment runs only once after install, reproducibly

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Following the local development setup instructions for Angular 2 at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html on Windows 10 works for the first run of the local development environment.  Both "npm install" and "npm start" work fine.  However, after closing all programs and trying again to run "npm start" there are console errors and an error log file, but the browser doesn't open.

Three times I've done a fresh install/start on Angular's quickstart files, and each time it fails to run after the initial setup as described above.

Solutions in other threads didn't work or were not applicable, but I'm including the contents of package.json since some issues previously discussed have referenced that file.

I followed the instructions in the command line outputs to report the problem to the "author" but got no response.

The "Report issues" link at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/learning-angular.html directs people to pose questions on GitHub, but the administrators on GitHub respond to a detailed post in their particular format within 20 seconds saying to post instead on StackOverflow.

I'd appreciate help in workarounds or suggestions on how to actually report problems to the Angular folks.

Here are the 3 items that seem most relevant:

command line:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\js\quickstart>npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart C:\Users\username\Documents\js\quickstart
> npm run build


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build C:\Users\username\Documents\js\quickstart
> tsc -p src/

src/app/hero.service.ts(22,2): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
src/app/hero.service.ts(34,2): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script 'tsc -p src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc -p src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\Documents\js\quickstart\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\Documents\js\quickstart\npm-debug.log
```

npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.9.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\username\Documents\js\quickstart\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: CWD: C:\Users\username\Documents\js\quickstart
9 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
10 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
11 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: Failed to exec prestart script
12 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
12 verbose stack Exit status 1
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
12 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
12 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
13 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
14 verbose cwd C:\Users\username\Documents\js\quickstart
15 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
16 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
17 error node v6.9.5
18 error npm  v3.10.10
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
20 error Exit status 1
21 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
21 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
21 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
21 error not with npm itself.
21 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
21 error     npm run build
21 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
21 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
21 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
21 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
21 error There is likely additional logging output above.
22 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: I should add that merely running "npm install" and "npm start" is not a workaround to "npm start" not working.  But starting with a new quickstart seed from https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip and running "npm install" and "npm start" does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more fundamental answer is to use an IDE such as https://code.visualstudio.com/ that will flag errors in the code regardless of when they occurred.  The combination of VSCode with extensions such as the following prevents annoyances such as described in this thread:

- TypeScript Hero
- TSLint
- angular2-inline

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  The error was pointed out by these lines:

```
src/app/hero.service.ts(22,2): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.

src/app/hero.service.ts(34,2): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
```

Fixing the error in the hero.service.ts file fixed the problem.  The confusing part was that the files kept working while the local development environment was running, despite having an error.  The error was only evident when restarting the server.

In another demo folder there was another error, a missing comma in an @NGModule declarations array.  The same issue occurred - the local development environment didn't complain while it was still open, but wouldn't restart.

This sounds like it could be a caching problem, and like caching problems it was confusing to someone unfamiliar with this environment.